# why not eliminating the need to padding bytes regarding this structure?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, padding, memory-alignment

Consider following simple structure:

```
struct Struct {
public:
  char  a;
  short int b;
  char  c;
};
```

If instances of this structure are placed at an even (16-bit-aligned) address, two padding bytes are required to fix the alignment (both for `b` and for any following instance in an array).

However, instances *could* be placed at an odd address, and then alignment would still be correct even with no padding bytes.

So I made a test and observed Visual C++ 2010 will add those two padding bytes and this indicates it always places them at even addresses.

Why wouldn't VC++ place them at odd addresses, saving 2 bytes per each object?
Is there something I'm not aware of?

Comment: I tried parsing the following sentence, but gave up after two attempts: *If objects of this structure always get placed at some address of memory that isn't multiple of two then without any padding, aligned memory access would apply to every member of those even when there is an array of them and size of each object would be 4 bytes, but if they always get placed at even addresses then two padding bytes are needed to be added to objects to allow aligned memory access making their size 6 and increased by two.*

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but if the question is how to get rid of padding in that structure, you can add the statement [`#pragma pack(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before the definition; that should change the size to `4`.

Comment: Having the elements properly aligned might improve performance, at the cost of wasting some space. How is the compiler to know that you want to save space but don't care about performance? Do you have a billion records, so the space is important?

Comment: @BoPersson The question is why the compiler doesn't choose a solution that achieves both goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that if that struct was layed out with no padding, then it could be placed at an odd address and its members would each, individually, be properly aligned.

The problem is how the compiler would go about placing it at an odd address. For sure that could be arranged for a variable of automatic storage. But what about a heap allocate variable allocated by `malloc`? The contract that `malloc` adheres to is that it must return a block of memory that is properly aligned for objects of any type. And `malloc` could never do that if there were some objects that needed to be placed at odd addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this problem by making it look like this:

```
struct Struct{
public:
    short int b;
    char a;
    char c;
};
```

This causes `sizeof(Struct) == 4` on many compilers

Comment: This is certainly true, but it hardly addresses the question that was actually asked.

Comment: But it does solve the problem the asker is facing, which is 'wasted space'. Admittedly, the other David (you) gave a more interesting answer than mine.

Comment: Well, we don't know what the "problem" is. Perhaps @Pooria is trying to understand why things are the way they are.